# How would I convert a ppm file to an OpenGL texture?

Tags: c++, opengl, file-io, byte

I have a P6 PPM image file format.

It stores each value as a byte.

As I understand I need to read it into a char * array, and feed it to OpenGL, but I'm not sure how to go about reading it in.

will something like this work?

```
for (i number of pixels to read)
char toAdd;
image.read(&toAdd, 1); 
charArray[i] = toAdd
```

The main problem seems to be that it isn't reading the file format properly. And I don't quite understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Per OpenGL you do not *need* to have it in a char array. This is rather just one of many options available with OpenGL. If you google for "OpenGL texture example" you'll find tons of examples out there:

- [Nullterminator](http://www.nullterminator.net/gltexture.html)
- [NeHe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/texture_mapping/12038/)

Whether your example works depends on how your `file` type works.

On [This page here](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~cse872/tutorial4.html) the author gives anoter example for texture mapping. He claim that his code is capable of reading PPM file format. There is also [another SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290870/texture-mapping-c-opengl) that goes into texture mapping.